# Management Plane protection (MPP)

Tags: cisco-commands, management

I'm new to networking. I was trying to understand What MPP is ? What kind of attacks is it preventing? How is it securing router from those attacks?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from Cisco:

> The management plane is the logical path of all traffic related to the
>   management of a routing platform. One of three planes in a
>   communication architecture that is structured in layers and planes,
>   the management plane performs management functions for a network and
>   coordinates functions among all the planes (management, control,
>   data). The management plane also is used to manage a device through
>   its connection to the network.
>
> Examples of protocols processed in the management plane are Simple
>   Network Management Protocol (SNMP), Telnet, HTTP, Secure HTTP (HTTPS),
>   and SSH. These management protocols are used for monitoring and for
>   CLI access. Restricting access to devices to internal sources (trusted
>   networks) is critical.
>
> Management Plane Protection Feature The MPP feature in Cisco IOS
>   software provides the capability to restrict the interfaces on which
>   network management packets are allowed to enter a device. The MPP
>   feature allows a network operator to designate one or more router
>   interfaces as management interfaces. Device management traffic is
>   permitted to enter a device through these management interfaces. After
>   MPP is enabled, no interfaces except designated management interfaces
>   will accept network management traffic destined to the device.
>   Restricting management packets to designated interfaces provides
>   greater control over management of a device.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/security/configuration/guide/sec_mgmt_plane_prot.html#wp1049321